# If I make a program do my work for me in an IT office job, could that deduct from my worked hours?

Tags: work-time

Theoretically, let's say you have an office job of organising and formatting documents.

But you program a bot, (software application) to do the job for you faster and without the need for much iteration.

Does the bots operational work time still contribute to my office hours? Does it still count as me working while I get more time to attend to other tasks?

In summary this question specifically relates to what represents your work hours in a standard / general workplace.

> - The hours of you perform personally in first person

Or

> - The hours you work in the 3rd person from your intention and skills being imposed by an automated bot you created.

Comment: Are you still sitting in your chair? Or did you start the bot and go home after lunch?

Comment: Still sitting in my chair, present if needed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49277/discussion-on-question-by-user2376870-if-i-make-a-program-do-my-work-for-me-in-a).

Comment: I have edited this question to explain in detail how it is generalized to a workplace and not off topic. Please reconsider it being closed as off-topic.

Comment: Your edit doesn't really add anything new. Your question was already *clear*, you just elaborated what was implicitly understood. It still remains a company a specific question that only your manager and/or company policy can answer.

Comment: @MaskedMan I think i am describing the question incorrectly if someone thinks what condones a work hour is "a company a specific question".

Comment: A work hour is an hour you spend working on tasks the employer (and specifically, your manager) assigns to you. Your real question is not what constitutes a work hour, but what constitutes *work*, and that *is* company specific.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**No: as an employee, you are expected to work X hours per week.**

If you want to be paid based on results alone, regardless of effort, you need to work as an independent contractor.

*Employees* are contracted based on working a set number of hours, in addition to an expected level of performance.

So, if you finish your assigned tasks in much less time than expected, that is great, your job performance is excellent--but you should still be working during all those hours you saved.  Ask your boss about what other tasks you can do, or if you are unable to get enough work assigned to you, take the initiative to identify things you could do that would benefit the company, and work on those (run them by your boss first where appropriate).

Of course, you *might* get away with just running your bot and sitting around doing nothing.  But this is a risky course of action: your actions (or lack thereof) would most likely be considered unacceptable if discovered.   In addition, you never want to be an unnecessary employee.  It's much better for your career to build on your success and keep doing good work.

Comment: I would argue it is more of a Salary vs Wage discussion. Salaried employees are paid to complete a piece of work. Waged employees are paid to complete X amount of hours of work per week. I think it is not an accident that programmers are rarely waged employees.

Comment: @Aron not correct in my view.  For salaried employees there typically *is* an expectation about number of hours worked, even if pay is not directly tied to that.  If you are a full time employee but only work, say, 20 hours per week, that almost no employer is going to consider that OK, even if you are more than twice as productive as other employees.

Comment: the warm body interpretation...for many Salaried jobs, part in parcel of that job is to be available and be able to answer questions. That does not mean they have to be actively working... However, I would argue that going right upto the limitations of your job description is a recipe for a self limiting career....

Comment: @Aron: “for many Salaried jobs, part in parcel of that job is to be available and be able to answer questions. That does not mean they have to be actively working” — you might want to check your employment contract to see if that’s actually what it says.

Comment: @dan1111 If I had an employee getting a week's worth of work done in a day, I would want to retain him, regardless of what he's doing the other 32 hours per week, though I would expect him to seek more duties.

Comment: And this is the painful realization about being a hired employee.

Answer (score 11):

This is something you need to ask your boss. If they decide to keep paying your hours, then you get paid for these hours.

More likely, they will either move you to a better position instead (if it's a good company) or take your bot and fire you (if it's a bad company).

Comment: I would not recommend asking your boss "Can I just sit here doing nothing, since I automated my assigned tasks?"  Instead I would say "I have automated my assigned tasks; what can I work on now?"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49258/discussion-on-answer-by-erik-if-i-make-a-program-do-my-work-for-me-in-an-it-offi).

Answer (score 7):

First you'd always need to ask your boss, but you'd need to know what to say and what you're doing to keep it operational.

Let’s take the IT departments for example, they need to maintain the servers and clients from breaking down, making sure everything is operational. If everything works, they basically sit on their asses doing nothing. (well, not nothing but you get my point) Quote from the comments below:

> When the servers are not broken down and panic reigns in the area,
>   they need to study their field, fix tiny problems on the floor, ask
>   for more work outside their field, etc. Basically, they look for work
>   that they can do while their primary task does not need their
>   attention. Of-course, nearly none of this is within their job
>   description.

So what you're doing is making sure your program is operational. Not only that, you also have to update it and possibly upgrade it for any unforeseen changes that happen within the company.

You could argue that the company could give this responsibility to someone else in the company, However that simply means they would lose control of the program, as you're the one who developed it.

*Depending on the size of the program you have, x amount of responsibility is placed on you. Added responsibility often equals an increase in salary.*

In the end, will you be able to deduct this from your hours made? possibly yes, possibly not. However, it could still give an increase in salary as you've taken the responsibility to develop such a key aspect of your job.

Talk to your manager/boss, tell him about the development of this program and the added responsibility you now have for maintaining it. In your next salary negotiations you should ABSOLUTELY mention this. You might even be given more responsibilities based off of your initiative.

Comment: "not nothing but you get my point"--I don't get this.  Whether or not they are *actually* doing nothing seems key to this question.

Comment: @dan1111 When the servers are not broken down and panic reigns in the area, they need to study their field, fix tiny problems on the floor, ask for more work outside their field, etc. basically, they look for work that they can do while their primary task does not need their attention. Of-course, nearly none of this is within their job description.

Comment: yes.  Given that the OP is basically asking "can I sit and do nothing during down time" that very good information should be a part of your answer.

Comment: @dan1111 I'm no good with words so I just added it to the answer in a quote like this. Thanks :)

Comment: @DouglasGaskell it did say "often" not "always".